# How to use this form_open_multipart?

Tags: codeigniter-3

```
    <?php echo form_open_multipart('uploads/do_upload');?>
```

This is from codiegnater documentation. But cant use it because of this error Message: Call to undefined function form_open_multipart()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```